# ComboBox Input ,wpf

Tags: wpf, combobox

I have a ComboBox and its items source is an SQL table.

I would like that the user will choose the value he likes and if the value is not in the list, he would be able to type the value into the ComboBox. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the IsEditable property of the ComboBox to True. This will allow you to edit the contents as well as select any of the populated items in the combo box.